# yii2 gridview daterangepicker kartik

Tags: gridview, yii2, daterangepicker

I use yii2 gridview widget with kartik daterangepicker for search records by date. All works fine except for one, I defined validation rules for search model and special field, after that i called widget initialization in my view.

Problem: Validation errors are not displayed under the input field when falidation fails, like it usually hapenned in GridView. 
I can manualy print error using next trick.

```
/* TRICK */
HTML::error($searchModel,'createdAt')
```

But i think that is not best way to chief my goal. Why are not errors displayed and help block with error does not append to the table cell?

```
[
    'attribute'=>'createdAt',
    'format'=>'html',
    'value'=>function($model) { return echo 'some value'; }
    'filter'=>DateRangePicker::widget(
             'model'=>$searchModel,
             'attribute' => 'createdAt',
             'pluginOptions'=> [
                 'locale'=>['format' => 'Y-m-d'],
                  "opens"=>"left",
             ]
    )] . HTML::error($searchModel,'createdAt') // TRICK
]
```

Used software:
yii 2.0.12;
kartik-v/yii2-date-range 1.6.8